# Getting error while running jaiImageIO.exe files

Tags: java, jai

I need to undate an .tiff image using Java.

There are 4 jars on oracle site to download the jaiImageIO jars.

1. jai_imageio-1_0_01-lib-windows-i586-jdk.exe
2. jai_imageio-1_0_01-lib-windows-i586-jre.exe
3. jai_imageio-1_0_01-lib-windows-i586.exe
4. jai_imageio-1_0_01-windows-i586-jar

I downloaded all the four jars, but when I try to run first one i.e jdk.exe getting error "Jdk 1.4 or higher is required" but I already have jdk1.7 installed in my system. Can anyone please suggest me how should I proceed. While running jre.exe its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `jai_imageio-1_0_01-lib-windows-i586.exe`. it will install libs on your machine. `.exe` with jre/jdk suffixes will always check for certain JRE/JDK.

Comment: What is your JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin;

Comment: That is not correct. JAVA_HOME must be till jdk directory not till bin

Comment: this is my path.. I am not setting any JAVA_HOME.
 i tried by putting lib.exe file inside the jdk bin folder. 
Its installed now. I set my class path : C:\Users\JavaPrg\Programs;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sun Microsystems\JAI Image IO Tools 1.0_01;%classpath% .
Do i need to set anything else..?

Comment: Yes, you should set JAVA_HOME in your environment variables.

Comment: done till jdk Path :C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55.
Still not working. getting null pointer exception.
Is there any other way to read .tiff

Comment: Please ask a fresh question showing your code and exception stack trace.

Comment: imgeIOjre.exe is also installed. i have the "jai_imageio-1_0_01-windows-i586-jar" too in my classpath.

importing "import javax.imageio.*;" in code and using Bufferreader to read the .tiff file

Comment: PF the code here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051253/i-am-not-able-to-read-tiff-images