# i am not able to read tiff images

Tags: java, jai

Here is my code. I am pasting an image over another image. This is working fine for .gif and .jpg but getting Null Pointer Exception for reading tiff images.

```
import java.awt.*;   
import java.awt.image.*;   
import java.io.*;     
import javax.media.jai.*; 
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Paint {   

    public static void main ( String args[] ) {   
        try {   
            // Create output file   
            OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream( "C:\\Users\\JavaPrg\\images\\image12.tif" );   

            // Load specified foreground and background    
            BufferedImage fgImage = ImageIO.read( new File( "C:\\Users\\JavaPrg\\images\\sign.png" ) );   
            BufferedImage bgImage = ImageIO.read( new File( "C:\\Users\\JavaPrg\\Input\\def.tif" ) );   


            BufferedImage tmpImage = new BufferedImage( fgImage.getWidth(), fgImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );   
            Graphics gOut = tmpImage.createGraphics();   

            // draw the foreground image on the temporary image   
            gOut.drawImage( fgImage, 0, 0, null );   
            gOut.dispose();   


            int width = tmpImage.getWidth();   
            int height = tmpImage.getHeight();   
            int[] pixels = new int[ width * height ];   
            pixels = tmpImage.getRGB( 0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width );   
            for ( int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++ ) {   
                Color c = new Color( pixels[i] );   

                int r = c.getRed();   
                int g = c.getGreen();   
                int b = c.getBlue();   

                c = new Color( r, g, b);
                pixels[i] = c.getRGB();   
            }   
            tmpImage.setRGB( 0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width );   


            Graphics bgc = bgImage.createGraphics();   
            bgc.drawImage( tmpImage,1110 ,425 , null );   
            bgc.dispose();   

            // Save the new composite image   
            ImageIO.write( bgImage, "tif", outStream );   
            outStream.close();   
        }   
        catch ( Exception x ) {   
            x.printStackTrace();   
        }   
    }   
}
```

not able to post the screenshot:
it's 
java.lang.NullPointerException at Paint.main

Comment: You need to install an image reader that knows how to read tiff files. Try https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys

Comment: I checked wht reader or writer i m having.
It has everything except Tiff. This is my output of that..
reader BMP
reader bmp
reader jpg
reader JPG
reader wbmp
reader jpeg
reader png
reader PNG
reader JPEG
reader WBMP
reader GIF
reader gif
writer jpg
writer BMP
writer bmp
writer JPG
writer jpeg
writer wbmp
writer png
writer PNG
writer JPEG
writer WBMP
writer GIF
writer gif

can i mannually register .tif reader and writer in code

Comment: is jai_imageio.jar is in class-path?

Comment: yup path of jar is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\lib\ext\jai_imageio.jar" 
classpath is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\jre\lib\ext;.;"

Comment: now ImageIO jdk.exe jre.exe and lib.exe everything is installed

Comment: The most simple solution seems to be to not write the output as a .tif file, is it possible to use .png (or something else) instead?

Comment: yeah output file format is not an issue... 
But i am not able to read the tiff file.
I checked Jars is at the Place. classpath set .
I checked in Jar in has the ImageIOtiffwriterspi but not able to load..
I tried using code too

public static void register(){
  IIORegistry registry = IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();   
  registry.registerServiceProvider(new TIFFImageWriterSpi());   
  registry.registerServiceProvider(new TIFFImageReaderSpi()); 

 }

but still getting error
NoClassdefFound

Comment: No Help!!! ?? :(
how to load these classes

Comment: The error is in Loading the classes from the Jar.
Is there any other method to load the TiffImage Writer/Reader classes

Comment: Did you try TwelveMonkeys?

Comment: I am not getting how to use that exactly.
Should i copy the code and create and package and then try.
Please suggest. How to procced with that

Comment: There are instructions in the repo; basically, just put the classes or jars in your classpath. If you're using maven, just adding the dependency is enough; otherwise you'll have to compile this (easiest using maven) and put that jar on your classpath. If you need help with that, it's a separate question (though I'd encourage you to try to read up on docs online first, because it's a fairly broad question that probably wouldn't do well on SO).

Comment: i am not using any IDE my code is in notepad using cmd only. i am having time constraints. now i am focused to convert tiff to jpg format.

Comment: Even in conversion i m getting the same error while running NoClassDefFound Error. its compiled properly while running this is the erroe what can be the issue